# Google search for "unit of impulse"

Tags: google-search

When I search on Google for "unit of impulse", it returns Newton, which is unit of force. Does anyone know why that happens?

https://www.google.com/search?q=unit+of+impulse&oq=unit+of+impulse&aqs=chrome.0.35i39i457j0l6j69i60.1858j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Is this a [SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seo) (Search Engine Optimisation) or a [physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) question ?

Comment: @pjmg it's a SEO question. I'm asking why Google got it wrong, instead of what the proper unit of impulse is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because Google is not perfect. Please click on the "Send feedback" shown below the [knownledge panel](https://support.google.com/knowledgepanel/answer/9163198?hl=en) and send your feedback to Google.

---

The following screen shot was taken from the results page for your [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=unit%20of%20impulse&oq=unit%20of%20impulse&aqs=chrome.0.35i39i457j0l6j69i60.1858j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) shown to me. It shows a *knowledge panel* having as title *Newton* but the summary snippet was taken from the Impulse (physics) article from Wikipedia. It shows the word "newton" in bold as it was a *term* when in this case the term is *newton second*

Some how the relationship between the term Newton and the Wikipedias article for Impulse was not correctly presented in the results page.

[image]